# Use Serilog default ITextFormatter for Serilog.Sinks.AwsCloudWatch

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, serilog

I am using Serilog to log information in my .NET Framework 4.7.2 solution. I am trying to use the **Serilog.Sinks.AwsCloudWatch** package to log information to AWS CloudWatch.

I have my credentials and other options setup for `CloudWatchSinkOptions`, except for the `TextFormatter` property. I do not want to use a custom implementation of `ITextFormatter`. How can I use the default Serilog formatter that I use in other sinks, such as **Serilog.Sinks.EventLog** and **Serilog.Sinks.Console**? I have not had to provide a `TextFormatter` for any other Serilog Sink and don't want to make one just for this.

I looked at the documentation  for Serilog and for the CloudWatch sink, but I could not find any helpful information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the answer on the GitHub page for Serilog. The default formatter is `Serilog.Formatting.Json.JsonFormatter`. Instantiating that class and passing it to the AWS CloudWatch sink fixed the issue.